# Display a message on visitors first visit

Tags: sessions, cookies

I am wanting to display a message when a visitor lands on the site for the first time.

I don't necessarily want to use browser cookies, but would if thats the only solution.

Ideally, would I be better off storing an IP of a visitor in the db?

Something to this effect:

```
{if first_visit}Welcome Message{/if}
```

Comment: Storing the IP address of every visitor for this purpose will not scale well. I'd recommend against -- cookies are the way to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [Show Once](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/show-once). It does use cookies, but other than that it is probably just what you are looking for.

From the add-on page:

> Show Once is the module for ExpressionEngine 2 that allows showing
>   certain content to a user only once (during their first visit). The
>   content that you want to show needs to be wrapped in
>   {exp:show_once:check} tag pair.

```
{exp:show_once:check code="twitter"}
  Do not forget to follow us on Twitter!
{/exp:show_once:check}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be to use [First-timer](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/first-timer). It allows you to redirect a user to a certain page when they login for  the first time.

Answer (score 0):

To add my two cents: I had exactly the same issue as the OP, but am working on EE 3, where Show Once and First-timer are not ready.

I got around this by using:

```
{exp:member:custom_profile_data}
  {if last_visit == "0"}Message{/if}
{/exp:member:custom_profile_data}
```

It works so far! Hope this is of help to someone.