# First Visit Alert And Latest Updates For Non Members

Tags: sessions, messages

EE 5.2.6

I'd like to be able to display messages to first time visitors and also show update messages to returning visitors but only show once. ***They don't have to be registered members.***

the Show Once and First Timer plugins are not up to date with EE 5 and the non-plugin option suggested [here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/851/display-a-message-on-visitors-first-visit) only works for members who are registered.

Is there any good way that you know to do this or a plugin that handles such things?

Answer (score 2):

To be able to do this at all EE would need to know information about past browsing behaviour of your visitors.  This in turn would require you to either record information about the visit in the EE database (e.g. IP address / dates) or plant information on the visitors devices via cookies or some such.  Both of these actions would be covered by GDPR and so to be able do either you would need to first get active permission from the visitor - which I am guessing would defeat your aims of responding to people without their registration or intervention.

So probably you cannot - but the limitation that prevents this is not EE related.

HTH

Comment: That's weird because it's something you see on a ton of sites. I wonder if it's more of an illusion than an actual first visit trigger. I suppose I can do some stuff with sessions and a plugin easily enough, though. Thanks for your response!

Comment: You could use the IP address (as it is passively collected by the log file etc.) but then you'd not be doing it per user but per IP address (so when hit by users from a shared IP you would only show 'first visit' info to the very first and rest would not see..., and only one would see second visit...).  It may be that in some jurisdictions the GDPR rules (or some clone of) don't apply - and certainly pre-GDPR I imagine this and more was done routinely.